# Persistence of data from different layouts android

Tags: android, persistence, orientation

I was doing an android application, in which I have two different layouts for the same activity (one for portrait and one for landscape, it is important to say that they are totally different). Well my problem the persistence of data between them, since when changing between portrait and landscape the data is lost, to try to solve my problem I used onSaveInstanceState and change the manifest, but none of them serves in my case. I hope you can help me, regards.

pd. Landscape is in the directory layout-land

```
mensaje=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextAlarma); //portrait
horaEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextHoras); //landscape
minutosEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMinutos); //landscape
segundosEdit=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSegundos); //landscape
mensajeTimer=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mensajeTimer); //landscape

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("msj",mensaje.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("hora",horaEdit.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("min",minutosEdit.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("seg",segundosEdit.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("msjT",mensajeTimer.getText().toString());

}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    String m=savedInstanceState.getString("msj");
    String h=savedInstanceState.getString("hora");
    String mn=savedInstanceState.getString("min");
    String s=savedInstanceState.getString("seg");
    String mt=savedInstanceState.getString("msjT");
    mensaje.setText(m);
    horaEdit.setText(h);
    minutosEdit.setText(mn);
    segundosEdit.setText(s);
    mensajeTimer.setText(mt);

}
```

Comment: post your code to show how you are using onSaveInstanceState - are you actually re-setting the values from the savedInstanceState bundle?

Comment: already edited the post

Answer (score 2):

## Override this two methods from your activity

Then when orientation changes just get the value in **onRestoreInstanceState** and set it to xml widget

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //SAVE YOUR DATA HERE
    outState.putString("key","Value");
    //YOU CAN SAVE ANY TYPE OF DATA HERE AND RETRIVE

}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //RETRIVE YOUR DATA HERE
    String value=savedInstanceState.getString("key");
    //SET VALUE TO XML HERE
    Log.d("Value saved is:",value);
    
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? (@Pavan should probably do the super call after the op in onSave)

Comment: i.e., do you see empty strings or something? Post the contents of the bundle as it comes back when the activity is restarted

Comment: didnt work, because in landscape there are 3 editText that do not exist in the portrait. What I want is that the information of portrait only remains in the portrait and the same in landscape

Comment: my big trouble is  this, when  i call onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState), i try save some editText, but some editEdixt doesnt exist in this layout and the following error appears
  Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText ()' on a null object reference

Comment: @eloylopez you should have declared all the edit text in both the xml files(Po-trait and Landscape)with same **ID** or **TAG**. You can change only View(User interface) using portrait and landscape but both should have widgets with matching **ID** else you will get exception. So you should have all 5 edittext in both XML files